# Building Maven via IntelliJ succeeds, but using the command line it fails

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Using the following command, IntelliJ can deploy the project successfully.

`"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.282.8-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\project_folder\sdrem\the_maven_project\sample-project\1.0.0 "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=55458:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.3.3 deploy -P profile1`

However, when I use the following command, build error occurs.

`mvn -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 deploy -P profile1`

What do I have to do to make this work? Why is plexus classworlds needed?

Comment: What is the error you have?

Comment: Without further information about the error, it's hard to say. However, be aware that IntelliJ is using `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3`, which is most probably not the same maven declared in your `PATH` for `mvn`.